# Animation & Rigging - Re-orienting bones in an IK rig for a different proportion characters

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

Probably half this question isn't entirely blender specific. But if I make a rig for a squat biped and create a set of animations, and then create another character that is tall and narrow when I re-position the rig to fit the proportions of the second character the animations go haywire.

Is there a system of constraints or something I can setup to make re-using a single rig and animations for large range of characters that are much different from the original?

Comment: This operation is known as "retargeting" and it's  quite a huge topic to be detailed in a simple answer, you can try to search infos and tutorials about.

Comment: it should not go haywire, maybe share a file with the 2 characters and armatures that share the same animations